# App crashing because of paused animation and NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uikit

I animate a UIView on and off the screen by pulling up and swiping down. I use this code to do that:

```
private var _animator: AnyObject?
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
var animator: UIViewPropertyAnimator? {
    get {
        return _animator as? UIViewPropertyAnimator
    }
    set {
        _animator = newValue
    }
}
var haveTheySwiped = false
var haveTheyNotSwiped = true

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func handlePan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let vel = recognizer.velocity(in: self)
        switch recognizer.state {
        case .began:
            if vel.y < 0 && !haveTheySwiped {
                animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 1, curve: .easeOut, animations: {
                    self.backgroundImage.frame = self.backgroundImage.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: -603)
                })
                haveTheySwiped = true
                isScanVisible = true
            } else if vel.y > 0 && haveTheySwiped {
                animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 1, curve: .easeOut, animations: {
                    self.backgroundImage.frame = self.backgroundImage.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: 603)
                })
                haveTheySwiped = false
                isScanVisible = false
            }
            animator?.pauseAnimation()
            print(backgroundImage.frame.origin)
        case .changed:
            let translation = recognizer.translation(in: backgroundImage)
            if vel.y < 0 {
                animator?.fractionComplete = translation.y / -603
            } else if vel.y > 0 && haveTheySwiped == true {
                animator?.fractionComplete = translation.y / 603
            }
        case .ended:
            animator?.continueAnimation(withTimingParameters: nil, durationFactor: 0)
        case .possible: break
        default: break
        }
}
```

But, recently I have come across a bug. When I try to pull up, the UIView does not appear and then when I lift my finger up, the app crashes with this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'It is an error to release
>   a paused or stopped property animator. Property animators must either
>   finish animating or be explicitly stopped and finished before they can
>   be released.'

Has anyone come across this? Would love some help figuring out what is causing this to happen. Any help would be immensely appreciated. Thanks so much in advance!

Cheers,
Thoe

Comment: @solenoid thanks so much for the comment! my function is in fact tied to the view, instead of triggering the animation. could you clarify what you're talking about?

Comment: The error is basically saying "hey, don't release me until I have in some way done my callback(either finished or cancelled in a proper way) because I am running on another thread". 

So instead, just use the input of your gestureRecognizer to move the incoming view with your finger. I cant test it now but there should be examples of that around.

Comment: @solenoid would u know what part of my code does that? just a little confused... hahaha

Comment: func stopAnimation(Bool)
Stops the animations at their current positions.
Required.
func finishAnimation(at: UIViewAnimatingPosition)
Finishes the animations and returns the animator to the inactive state.
Required. - these are probably whats missing, sorry for my brain farts

Comment: if you use `pausesOnCompletion = true` to fix the background bug in iOS 11
the app will also crash with the same error message.
If you activate this flag the animator stays in state `.active` even when it is completed. When the system now tries to clean up the memory the animator has to be in state `.inactive` otherwise the app will crash.

Answer (score 20):

In case somebody still gets this crash in 2019 or later, I had a similar issue with an animator I only needed to run for 25% of its fraction complete (to create a subtle blur on a collectionView cell).

The crash would occur when the cell would be deinit or when the VC would be popped from the navController.

Inside the UI setup of my cell, I had the below implementation

**Before: leading to crash**

```
 animator?.fractionComplete = 0.25
```

**After: no more crash**

```
 animator?.fractionComplete = 0.25
 animator?.stopAnimation(true) 
 animator?.finishAnimation(at: .current)
```

This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 5.x:**

```
animator?.stopAnimation(true)
if let animator = animator, animator.state != .inactive {
    animator.finishAnimation(at: .current)
}
```

Fixed problem in our case.

Answer (score 3):

Implementing stopAnimation(Bool) then finishAnimation(at: UIViewAnimatingPosition) should clear up the problem.

> This class adopts the  UIViewAnimating  and  UIViewImplicitlyAnimating
> protocols, which define the methods for starting, stopping, and
> modifying your animations. For more information about the methods of
> those protocols, see  UIViewAnimating  and  UIViewImplicitlyAnimating
> .

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewanimating

> func stopAnimation(Bool)
> Stops the animations at their current
> positions. Required.
>
> func finishAnimation(at: UIViewAnimatingPosition)
> Finishes the animations and returns the animator to the inactive
> state. Required.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer but it is still unclear where you want me to implement that. The handlePan() function is a new type of function this year. There was a talk about it at WWDC. Where should I add the stopAnimation and finishAnimation?

Comment: I dont have a mac handy, but I would add a completion handler to the animation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewpropertyanimator/1648373-addcompletion then put it in there. Also put it in any spot where the animation could get cancelled.

Comment: Completion blocks are executed after the animations finish normally. If you call the stopAnimation(_:) method, the completion blocks are not called if you specify true for the method’s parameter. If you specify false for the parameter, the animator executes the completion blocks normally after you call the its finishAnimation(at:) method.

Answer (score 2):

The error here is generally due to the fact that the System is trying to clear the animator before it is back to .inactive state.

I don see all your codes.

But generally, something like this will crash

```
  private func animating(){
    let animation = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 3, curve: .linear) {
        [weak self] in
        self?.view.backgroundColor = .red
    }

    animation.startAnimation()
    animation.pauseAnimation()
}
```

When the animating function is completed, the system will try to clear the UIViewPropertyAnimator you have created (**the property does not live outside of the define scope**), but the animation is paused, which means it is still at the .active state (the same goes to animation.stopAnimation(), just that in this case it is .stop state), and like I mention above, anytime when you try to clear the animator before it is back on .inactive state, the system will throw an error.

So, the solution in this case, if you wish to pause or stop animation halfway, you need to find a way to **retain** the animator.

For example, you can create a property in the viewController like

```
var animation : UIViewPropertyAnimator!
```

But you need to make sure that the animator goes back to .inactive state before you allow the system to clear it, or else the crash will just happen again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and combining the knowledge of this question helped me solve the issue:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    
    articleHeader?.animator.stopAnimation(true)
    
    if let animator = articleHeader?.animator, animator.state != .inactive {
        animator.finishAnimation(at: .current)
    }
}
```

**@programmingbeginner** with his input "*But you need to make sure that the animator goes back to .inactive state before you allow the system to clear it, or else the crash will just happen again.*" helped me understand that we need to go back to .inactive before the UIViewController pops from the Navigation stack. The place to do this is viewWillDisappear().

You also need to keep a reference to the animator in your UICollectionView (my animator was in the ArticleHeader view).

**@atereshkov**: I am using his code to check whether the animator is still active.

To keep reference to the ArticleHeader animator in your UICollectionViewController:

```
var articleHeader: ArticleHeader?

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    // assign the header here
    articleHeader = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: ArticleHeader.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? ArticleHeader
    
    // do any header configuration here
   
    return articleHeader!
}
```

Hope it helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar bug that was happening intermittently. Something like `animator.startAnimation(afterDelay: 1)` crashed. Further more calling `stopAnimation` or `finishAnimation` it may still crash so checking the state of the animator made sure that it won't be called when it shouldn't.

```
if animator.state == .inactive {
animator.startAnimation(afterDelay: 1) 
}
```

Depending on your implementation you can handle it differently. However checking for the state of the animator will assure that the command causing the crash will not be called.

May not be exactly of help in the case of the OP but this answer comes up first for similar bugs where the animator is required to be in a particular state.

Answer (score 0):

The state of the animator should be `.inactive`.
To achieve this all you should need is to call `animator.stopAnimation(true)` at the right moment.

I was using it in a ViewController and had the crash when leaving the screen. I needed to call it just before `super.viewDidDisappear(animated)`.